# Revert back to Mavericks from Yosemite Public Beta

Tags: macos

I have downloaded the Mavericks OS X Installation and found out it did not work. It gave me this message:

> This copy of the "Install OS X" application is too old to be opened on this version of OS X.

I wanted to downloaded the public beta thinking it would be nice since I heard there was no problems. I ran into lots of performance problems on the way. I would like to go back to Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as beta software without problems.

Restore your system from a Time Machine backup taken before you installed the beta OS release. This is possible by booting into the Recovery Partition.

Answer (score 1):

As you were informed when installing the Yosemite preview, it is not possible to downgrade to Mavericks. You will require a backup to restore your machine to. Alternatively, you can boot from an install media, or use Internet Recovery to download a Recovery partition of an older OS.

Answer (score 1):

This article from MacWorld might be helpful. http://www.macworld.com/article/2458050/how-to-revert-to-mavericks-from-the-yosemite-public-beta.html

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.